# I am trying to get location name with location id using vue js

Tags: vue.js

When I select to location I want also to get the location name but unfortunatly getting location name wrong with location id please help me how can i solved thank u.

**locationList.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="q-gutter-md q-pa-sm col-md-3">
        <q-select
            v-model="location_id"
            filled
            label="Locations"
            :options="api.locations"
            bg-color="white"
            name="location_id"
            dense
            emit-value
            map-options
            option-label="name"
            option-value="id"
            @update:model-value="addLocation"
        />
    </div>
</template>
```

**script**

```
methods: {
        getLocations () {
            axios.get(process.env.API_URL + '/lookups/locations')
                .then(({ data: { items } }) => {
                    this.api.locations = items
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })
        },
        addLocation () {
            let locationName = null
            if (this.location_id != null) {
                locationName = this.api.locations.name
            }
            store.dispatch('location/storeLocation', {
                location_id: this.location_id,
                locations: locationName
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think `q-select` component is saving an object with value and label inside `location_id`. Is it `Quasar`?

Comment: Yes I am using quasar

Comment: Just I need to get location name related location id

Comment: According to docs you have two ways to use `q-select and v-model binding`.  I can't see `location_id` declaration but I think it is an `array of objects`, so maybe `location_id` have an object with the selected item. 

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select#example--object-options

EDIT: **I haven't used Quasar`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that api.locations is an array of objects you're not searching for the location name in addLocation. also are you sure that location_id is being set? if it is not you're just dispatching a store event with a null locationName

something like this would work better for you

```
addLocation () {
    let locationName = null
    if (this.location_id) {
        locationName = this.api.locations.find(item => item.id === this.location_id).name;
    }
    if(locationName) {
        store.dispatch('location/storeLocation', {
            location_id: this.location_id,
            locations: locationName
        })
    }
}
```

more information on searching arrays from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/12476007)